# how to get parent values from a child model's instance with foreign key using eager-loading in laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel-5, eager-loading

i have four models
    -User
    -Question
    -Answer
    -Comment

the User model contains

```
public function questions(){
        return $this->hasMany(Question::class);
 }
public function answers(){
        return $this->hasMany(Answer::class);
}
public function comments(){
        return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
}
```

the Question model contains

```
public function users(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class,'user_id','id');
}
public function answers(){
        return $this->hasMany(Answer::class);
}
public function comments(){
        return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
}
```

//the question table has user_id

the Answers model contains

```
public function questions(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Question::class,'user_id','id');
}
public function users(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
public function comments(){
        return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
}
```

//the answers table has user_id,question_id

the Comment model contains

```
public function questions(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Question::class);
}
public function users(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
public function answers(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Answer::class);
}
```

//the answers table has user_id,question_id,answer_id

whenever access the Question model
i can get access User,Answer,Comment related to that Question

but i want to get the details of the user that answers the question as well as the details of the user that commented on an answer.

this is my controller

```
public function show($slug){    
        $questionData = Question::with('users','answers','comments')->where('slug',$slug)->first();
         return view('questions.single',compact('questionData'));
}
```

but wheneva i do

```
@foreach($questionData->answers as $answer)
    $answer->user_id;
   //it retuns only the user_id from the answers table
   //how can i turn this to the username
@endforeach
```

i want to get the username of the user who answerd the question, as well as the username of the user that commented on the answer

Comment: Use `$answer->users()` you should access to relation

Comment: Thanks so much....ive solved it by creating a method in the Question model. UserColumnUserName($id) it returns the colection of a user related to the id specified...but your method is the best... I've tried it before , it ddint work...now i had to go to users() relation in Answer model to specify the foreing key and local key....thanks so much